# How do i change the metric of metricspanel in Grafana plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, aggregate, monitoring, grafana

i am trying to implement a plugin with an own tab.(In  the clockpanel it is the editor.html.. tab)
In this new created editortab i want to minimize the resultset of the metric panel aggreagations.

My defined settings in my extratab should set a predefined query. (Metric, Grouping, lucene..)
For example: in the extratab is a dropdown menu. One entry is 'showUser'.. the metricpanel aggregations should be set to grouped by user.. 
How do i do that?..

I really appreciate every help !